# How to get a modal JDialog to blink when user clicks outside it

Tags: java, swing

The blinking code isn't important, rather than how to catch the event that is fired when you click outside of the dialog (if there even is one). 
On Windows, if you do attempt to click outside the dialog, it sounds a `'ding'` sound and I was just wondering if it's possible to jump on that event's bandwagon. Is this possible?

Thanks.

**SSCCE:**

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ModalDialogSSCCE {
   private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Modal Dialog SSCCE - click to display dialog");
   private JPanel dialogContent = new JPanel();
   private ModalDialog dialog;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ModalDialogSSCCE();
   }

   public ModalDialogSSCCE() {
      Action closeAction = new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dialog.setVisible(false);
         }
      };

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

      JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
      closeButton.addActionListener(closeAction);

      dialogContent.setSize(200, 200);
      dialogContent.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
      dialogContent.add(closeButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      dialog = new ModalDialog(dialogContent, closeAction);

      frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            dialog.setVisible(true);
         }
      });

      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   }

   public class ModalDialog extends JDialog {

      private JComponent content;
      private final int shadowSize = 5;

      public ModalDialog(JComponent content, Action closeAction) {    
         this.setLayout(null);
         this.content = content;
         this.setUndecorated(true);
         AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
         this.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);  
         this.getContentPane().add(content);

         content.setBounds(shadowSize, shadowSize, content.getWidth(), content.getHeight());
         content.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED)
                .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "close");
         content.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "close");
         content.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
                .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "close");
         content.getActionMap().put("close", closeAction);
      }

      @Override
      public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
         super.paint(graphics);
         Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
         g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         g.setColor(new Color(50, 50, 50, 50));
         g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(shadowSize));
         g.drawRoundRect(shadowSize / 2 + 1, shadowSize / 2 + 1, getWidth() - shadowSize - 2, getHeight() - shadowSize - 2, 1, 1);
         content.repaint();
      }

      public void toggle() {
         if (isVisible()) this.setVisible(false);
         else this.setVisible(true);
      }

      @Override
      public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
         if (visible) {
            this.setBounds(frame.getX() + (frame.getWidth() - content.getWidth()) / 2,
            frame.getY() + (frame.getHeight() - content.getHeight()) / 2,
                           content.getWidth() + 2 * shadowSize,
                           content.getHeight() + 2 * shadowSize);
         }
         super.setVisible(visible);
      }

      public JComponent getContent() {
         return content;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: *"On Windows, if you do attempt to click outside the dialog, it sounds a 'ding'"*  That is incorrect.  The 'ding' only happens if the dialog is modal and the user clicks on another part of the ***application that owns the dialog.***

Comment: What do you want to do once you see the event?

Comment: @AndrewThompson That is correct. I implied that the click is within the application but not in the dialog itself. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @trashgod I want to have the title-bar blink between inverted and not-inverted colors twice, simply to draw attention to the dialog saying "sorry, you have unfinished business here."

Comment: It would indicate to me *"sorry, you are using a broken and irritating app., please uninstall me ASAP"*

Comment: What alternative would you suggest? Or rather, what would you expect? Was considering for the dialog to simply cancel and disappear.

Comment: Pop a [`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) where the `int` is `ERROR_MESSAGE`.

Comment: That is a classic SSCCE, and it proves my simplistic statements wrong.  Sorry for wasting your time.  Does the dialog have components that can gain focus?

Comment: Not at all, should have posted one in the first place. And yes, the dialog can and would have components that can gain focus.

Comment: Just to clarify, a "classic SSCCE" is a good thing?

Comment: A classic SSCCE is a good thing, but the code should be posted here, not on some other site so we can see the code without looking all over the web for the code.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Was trying to be concise.

Answer (score 1):

Make the dialog modal and give it a parent.  E.G. using the [`JDialog(Frame,String,boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) constructor.

```
JDialog blockingDialog = new JDialog(mainFrame, "Blocking Dialog", true);
```

Comment: What would giving it a parent achieve? Sorry if I can't see the reason / function for that straight away.

Comment: Try it without one.  Report back.

Comment: No difference, it seems. Looks like it might be time for an SSCCE.

Comment: Added a link to the SSCCE in the question.